# Происхождение слов "курить" и "курица"

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Общее ли происхождение слов "курить" и "курица"? Или они просто схожи по звучанию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Родственность не просматривается.
Оба корня - общеславянские, курить восходит к топить (печь), разжигать.
Курица, кура - сохранило древнейшее значение.

Не очень уверен, но судя по этимологическому ряду на праславянском уровне слова имели разный гласнй в корне, причем в западнославянских языках это различие сохранилось. Если это так, то вопрос родственности снимается.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что куры, курица, а также курить имеют отношение к слову "двор". Англ. - court, corte - итал. От латинского - папская курия - папский двор. Отсюда курица - дворовая птица, печи ставили во дворе, во избежание пожаров.

Answer (score 0):

Как известно, куры в своем диком состоянии водятся в Индии до сих пор; по-видимому, оттуда это одомашненное животное к нам и проникло. Петух тоже именовался "кур" - мужского рода. Однажды я спросила специалиста по санскриту об этом, и он сказал, что в санскрите "кур" обозначает "видящий": куры вообще и петухи в частности всегда, в любых условиях ощущают восход Солнца; петухи при этом начинают издавать громкие крики. Не могло ли вместе с животными быть заимствовано и их "обозначение" по самому характерному свойству?